# Filter array for all structs with specific name and remove them

Tags: arrays, swift, filter

I have an array `carsArray` of structs - each struct has a name. A name might be used several times inside of this array.

Let's say I have a car called **"Audi"** - how can I filter the given array of structs and delete every entry with the name **"Audi"** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Model**

```
struct Car {
   let name:String
}
```

**Filter & Remove** all items with a specific criteria

```
var arr = [Car]()
// fill the array here
arr.removeAll(where:{ $0.name == "Audi" })
```